# PullToRefresh Issue when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the Pull to refresh so when pulled at top of page the page reloads. This is for a web page and I want it to to act like mobile app on refresh.

Problem is if I scroll to bottom of page, even when I begin to scroll back up, it reloads. I only want to do it when the page reaches the top of page.

My code is below. I am using this for reference.
https://www.boxfactura.com/pulltorefresh.js/

```
  /* global PullToRefresh */
  PullToRefresh.init({
    mainElement: '#mainapp',
    onRefresh: function() { location.reload(); alert('refresh') }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never used this package, and it seems its purpose for mobile applications. However, you could check if the user is at the top of the page before reloading. Assuming this method will run every time the user scrolls up you can do something like this:

```
/* global PullToRefresh */
  PullToRefresh.init({
      mainElement: '#mainapp',
      onRefresh: function() {
           if (document.body.scrollTop === 0) {
               location.reload();
               alert('refresh');
           }
      }
  });
```

Comment: Problem with this is: It only refreshes at top. but skips and still runs to refresh every scroll up. Cant even make it back to top if on bottom.

Comment: Im a little confused, I thought you only wanted to refresh if you were at the top. And what do you mean by skip? like the scroll event is not registered?

Comment: I do want to refresh at the top. Want it to reload page when pulled down...Doing it that way it now reloads at top but now when I scroll to bottom and then try to go back to top it wont allow me to go to top. Skips, jumps and acts weird.